# Dropdown menu - save the choice on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create popup language dropdown menu with country name, flag and link to the language version of the site. After user select menu item - it should take you to the needed url (language version of the page) and this choice should stay visible on the new page (after reload). Example of the menu - https://prnt.sc/sjumj8 (https://www.farfetch.com/shopping/women/items.aspx)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to create: https://jsfiddle.net/Okean/8x0atLpy/62/

```
<body>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="select-lang">
        <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
        <li data-value="value 1"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197615.svg"> Language 1 </a> </li>
        <li data-value="value 2"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197386.svg">Language 2 </a> </li>
        <li data-value="value 3"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197484.svg">Language 3 </a> </li>
        <li data-value="value 4"> <a href="#"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/197/197380.svg">Language 4 </a> </li>
    </ul>
</body>


<script>

    $("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
        allOptions.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
        allOptions.toggle();
    });



    window.onload = function() {
        var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem");  
        $('#select-lang').val(selItem);
        }
        $('#select-lang').change(function() { 
            var selVal = $(this).val();
            sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", selVal);
        });
</script> 

<style>   
    body{
      padding:30px;
    }
    ul { 
        height: 30px;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px #000 solid;
    }
    ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
    ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
    ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
    li.init { cursor: pointer; }

    a#submit { z-index: 1; }

    li img {
      width: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ul>` tag element won't ever trigger a `.change` event,
you can't even use `li.val()` as it doesn't have an actual `value` attribue.

So you need to workaround a little, something like this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
 // cache selectors for better performance
  const listItem = $("ul");
  const listSelected = listItem.find('.init');
  const allOptions = listItem.children('li:not(.init)');

  listItem.on('click', '.init', () => {
    listItem.children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
  });


  listItem.on('click', 'li:not(.init)', (e) => {
    const that = $(e.target);
    const setHTML = that.html();
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    that.addClass('selected');
    listSelected.html(setHTML);
    allOptions.toggle();
    sessionStorage.setItem('SelItem', setHTML);
  });

  const selectItem = $("#select-lang");
  const storedItem = sessionStorage.getItem('SelItem');
  if (storedItem) {
    listSelected.html(storedItem);
  }
});
```

this should work as expected, storing target `<li>` HTML inside `SelItem` on sessionStorage

Comment: Amazing! Works! Thank you!

Comment: @Yurii you're welcome. anyway, I'm suggesting you to use a `<select>` on HTML to use normal `.change` event, using CSS to workaround its aspect, but no worries, glad to help :)

Comment: yeah, I actually started with <select> but than I thought it would be difficult to use <select> with different value attributes and different url inside each <select> + image so using <ul>,<li> tags seemed simpler. Thank you @CapitanFindus !